# My question is the first google result, but is so old that it contains misleading information. Should I worry?

Tags: discussion, obsolete-questions

In 2018 I [asked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/343557/how-can-we-assign-handicaps-in-our-age-of-empires-2-hd-games) about introducing a handicap system to my Age of Empires II HD games. The question contained the factual statement "Age of Empires II has no handicap system".

Since then, most of the community has migrated to a re-release, Age of Empires II DE, which will soon have a full-fledged handicap system. Age of Empires II HD still exists, but most people play DE now. I and others have updated my question to attempt to clarify that we're not talking about the latest release, but googling "age of empires 2 definitive edition handicap" gives this incorrect highlight:

[image: Google search results for age of empires 2 definitive edition handicap, with the incorrect statement "age of empires 2 has no handicap system" highlighted]

I'm getting renewed traffic to my question. Should I do anything else to make sure I don't end up misleading people, or should I leave the question in its current, obsolete, form?

Answer (score 13):

I feel a proper course of action would be to clarify through editing that your question from 2018 is **not** for *Age of Empires II DE*.

You can do something like this at the top of your post:

### Note: This post is about *Age of Empires II HD*, and not for Age of Empires II Definition Edition.

---

← Original Post Content →

It be even better if you could make a post specific to Age of Empires II DE that asks and answers the same question as your 2018 question (only now specific to the definition edition of the game) and include a link to it - once the handicap system is in place that is (I don't know the game, but by the sounds of your post the handicap system appears to be getting an update at some point).

We can't really control what search engines return as results.  I think most search engines consider the tags to a degree, but even then it still isn't 100% perfect.

If things start to get out of hand, we can always [protect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) the question to help prevent non-answers from being posted, and things like that.  Us moderators as well as higher reputation users have this ability.

Comment: Search engines also take a while to update this kind of information. From my own personal nonsense, Google took about 2 weeks to update some relevant information about my music, and that was by directly asking them to through a form. Google probably won't update that highlight immediately, but sometime soon it may be updated.

Comment: I'm not sure it'd be too useful for me to self-answer a question about the DE handicap system, since it's a pretty obvious feature built right into the game. Self-answering a question about how to assign handicaps in Definitive Edition is a bit like someone self-answering a question about how to equip a weapon in RuneScape - it's a pretty obvious button. Thanks for the guidance on what to do if things start getting out of hand, though!

Comment: @ymbirtt makes sense - if it isn't worth creating its own question for, then no need.